# Recursion and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have some problems with the code below. I am receiving input using `InputSreamReader`,`BufferReader`. I am getting an error message that states.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Illegal modifier for parameter findMin; only final is permitted

Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
```

Keep in mind that the code is not finished> I am just tring to determine what I am missing to get this error to dissapear.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    double [] numbers = new double[100];

    InputStreamReader streamR = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(streamR);
    String reader = inFile.readLine();
    / / This method finds the smallest number in an array looking at indexes startIndex and endIndex
    public static double findMin(double[] elements, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        if (endIndex == startIndex)               // base case
        {
            return elements[endIndex];
        }
        else     // recursive case to compare the min found so far
        {
            double previousMin = findMin(elements, startIndex, endIndex-1);
            if (previousMin > elements[endIndex])
                return elements[endIndex];
            else
                return previousMin;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One issue I see is, you have method inside another method. Move `findMin` definition outside `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an actual line in your code:

```
/ / This method finds the smallest number in an array looking at indexes startIndex and endIndex
```

then take note that single-line comments start with `//` and no spaces are allowed between the two slashes. The parser will not ignore the above line and will give you errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in this code,

```
1. Declare your findMin method outside your main.
2. Remove the space between / / and should be // This method finds the smallest number in an array looking at indexes startIndex and endIndex
```